# annotate equation in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
curve(dnorm, from = -3, to = 3, n = 1000)
text(-2, 0.3, expression(f(x) == paste(frac(1, sqrt(2 * pi * sigma^2)),
                                       " ", e^{
                                         frac(-(x - mu)^2, 2 * sigma^2)
                                       })), cex = 1.2)
```

How can I add the above expression text in `ggplot2`? If I use expression then I get error saying input must be a vector, not an expression.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-3, 3)), aes(x))+
  stat_function(fun = dnorm)+
  annotate("text", label = , 
           x = -2, 
           y = 0.3, 
           color = "black")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Label
Lab <- expression(f(x) == paste(frac(1, sqrt(2 * pi * sigma^2)),
                         " ", e^{
                           frac(-(x - mu)^2, 2 * sigma^2)
                         }))
#Code
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-3, 3)), aes(x))+
  stat_function(fun = dnorm)+
  annotate("text", label = Lab, 
           x = -2, 
           y = 0.3, 
           color = "black",parse=T)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I still get ```Error: Input must be a vector, not an expression vector.```

Comment: @K.Maya Are you using other data? First test with the data you shared. Or re start `R` it might be a conflict with other package.

Comment: @K.Maya Aweeeesoooomeeeee! I knew there was an issue with other package!